# How to show 'Register New User' for all guests and something else for registered users?

Tags: module, articles, login, joomla-4

I want to build a simple site with Joomla 4. The webpage should only handle these few things:

1. **For guests (not logged in users):**

   Display an article with some text and the 'login mask' inside the article. There should be a link to 'register new user'.
2. **For logged in users:**

   Display an article with some text and a 'Log Out' button.

That's all.

---

Lodder pointed me to the possibility of adding modules into articles:

[image]

Comment: If you're using the same article, you can simply put the Login module inside said article.

Comment: Thank you, I found it. Thats brings me one step forward.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use two modules with different permissions.

For example, one for visitors (public) and one for registered users (all other groups).

[image: Module Permissions]

Comment: Thanks for coming over to JSE. Please take our [tour] and perhaps introduce yourself by editing your profile.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use the native ACL built on Joomla 4 without anything else.

Example:

- Create an article and choose access to "**Registered**" users.
- Split th earticle with using "Read more" tag after few lines.
- On the "Options" article tab, scroll down and choose "**Yes**" from "Unauthorised Links".
- Create a menu item with "Category Blog" type.
- On the "Options" menu item tab, choose "**Use Article Settings**" from "Unauthorised Links".

That's all.

The guest user will see the intro title and the intro text and at the end the "**Register to read more**".